# Pros and cons of using exec for importing a specific module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-exec

I would like to find out disadvantages of using `exec` for imports. One of the files serves as interface towards real implementations of specific functionalities depending on chosen project (framework is intended to work on several projects).

First use-case goes like this:

```
exec ("from API.%s.specific_API_%s import *" % (project, project))
```

This way I don't have to hard code anything except the variable `project` which is injected in the interface-module itself.

This is the other way:

```
if project == 'project_one':
    from API.project_one.specific_API_project_one import *
elif project == 'project_two':
    from API.project_two.specific_API_project_two import *
elif project == 'project_three':
    from API.project_three.specific_API_project_three import *
```

This way I have to alter this interface-file each time new project is added to be supported.

Comment: A possible third way would be to use `importlib.import_module` which takes a string argument to do the importing. This is probably better than using `exec`

Answer (score 3):

1. If you need programmatic way to import modules, please use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) or `__import__` (for really specific cases). Reasons — don't re-invent the wheel, there's way to do what you want without `exec`. If your `project` variable coming from outer world, `exec` is a huge security issue.
2. Wildcard imports considered bad practice — it makes harder to maintain your codebase afterwards.

---

Oversimplified example of issues with `exec` by executing arbitrary code:

```
module = 'request'
func = 'urlopen'
exec("from urllib.%s import %s" % (module, func))

func = 'urlopen; print("hello python")'
exec("from urllib.%s import %s" % (module, func))
```

yes, your example is harder to forge, but problem stays — giving python arbitrary code to execute is overkill (with potential security gap), when you have tool built exactly for your purpose — programatically importing modules.

Comment: Could you explain why exec is a huge security issue? I'm trying to understand do's and dont's rather than excepting them as is.